# Two column foreign key in entity framework

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013

I have two tables: `operation` and `operation_category_element_relation`.

The `operation` table has a composite primary key `operation_id: bigint` and `date_data: nvarchar(10)`. The `operation_category_element_relation` has these columns as well. There is a relationship between the tables based on these two columns. After adding the ADO.NET Entity Data Mode I get two errors:

> Error 13101: The types of all properties in the Dependent Role of a referential constraint must be the same as the corresponding property types in the Principal Role. The type of property 'operation_date_data' on entity 'operation_category_element_relation' does not match the type of property 'operation_id' on entity 'operation' in the referential constraint 'FK_operation_category_element_relation_operation'.

and

> Error 13101: The types of all properties in the Dependent Role of a referential constraint must be the same as the corresponding property types in the Principal Role. The type of property 'operation_id' on entity 'operation_category_element_relation' does not match the type of property 'date_data' on entity 'operation' in the referential constraint 'FK_operation_category_element_relation_operation'.

Can you please explain what the problem is and how to get rid of it?

The content of autogenerated edmx file is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<edmx:Edmx Version="3.0" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edmx">
  <!-- EF Runtime content -->
  <edmx:Runtime>
    <!-- SSDL content -->
    <edmx:StorageModels>
      <Schema xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm/ssdl"     Namespace="TEMPDataModel.Store" Alias="Self" Provider="System.Data.SqlClient" ProviderManifestToken="2005">
        <EntityContainer Name="TEMPDataModelTargetContainer"></EntityContainer>
      </Schema>
    </edmx:StorageModels>
    <!-- CSDL content -->
    <edmx:ConceptualModels>
      <Schema xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm" xmlns:cg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2006/04/codegeneration" xmlns:store="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/12/edm/EntityStoreSchemaGenerator" Namespace="TEMPDataModel" Alias="Self" xmlns:annotation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation" annotation:UseStrongSpatialTypes="false">
        <EntityContainer Name="TEMPDataModelContainer" annotation:LazyLoadingEnabled="true"></EntityContainer>
      </Schema>
    </edmx:ConceptualModels>
    <!-- C-S mapping content -->
    <edmx:Mappings>
      <Mapping xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/mapping/cs" Space="C-S">
        <Alias Key="Model" Value="TEMPDataModel" />
        <Alias Key="Target" Value="TEMPDataModel.Store" />
        <EntityContainerMapping CdmEntityContainer="TEMPDataModelContainer" StorageEntityContainer="TEMPDataModelTargetContainer"></EntityContainerMapping>
      </Mapping>
    </edmx:Mappings>
  </edmx:Runtime>
  <!-- EF Designer content (DO NOT EDIT MANUALLY BELOW HERE) -->
  <Designer xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edmx">
    <Connection>
      <DesignerInfoPropertySet>
        <DesignerProperty Name="MetadataArtifactProcessing" Value="EmbedInOutputAssembly" />
      </DesignerInfoPropertySet>
    </Connection>
    <Options>
      <DesignerInfoPropertySet>
        <DesignerProperty Name="ValidateOnBuild" Value="true" />
        <DesignerProperty Name="EnablePluralization" Value="true" />
        <DesignerProperty Name="IncludeForeignKeysInModel" Value="true" />
        <DesignerProperty Name="UseLegacyProvider" Value="false" />
        <DesignerProperty Name="CodeGenerationStrategy" Value="None" />
      </DesignerInfoPropertySet>
    </Options>
    <!-- Diagram content (shape and connector positions) -->
    <Diagrams></Diagrams>
  </Designer>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

Comment: What are the data types of `operation_id` and `date_data` in `operation_category_element_relation`? They need to be the same.

Comment: They are the same - I did not write it, but they are the same as correspondig columns in operations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer here: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1735

This happens for composite foreign keys ***if order of foreign key columns is different from the order of key columns in the principal table***. Sample tables that could be used to repro this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1] (
  [Id]       INT           NOT NULL,
  [IdString] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([IdString] ASC, [Id] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table3]
(
  [TableId] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  [IdString] NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
  [Id]       INT           NULL, 
  CONSTRAINT [FK_Table3_ToTable] FOREIGN KEY (IdString, Id) REFERENCES [Table1](IdString, Id),
)
```

---

UPD. In my case I also had to change the order of fields *according* to the order of fields in the PK.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you I had the same error, but in my case I had an issue where I was using a composite key using 3 columns, but the primary key in the table only specified 2 primary key columns (hard to explain, but clearly EF didnt like it)

Comment: Thanks! In my case I had to switch the order of composite keys in the foreign table to set the foreign key as the 1st key of the 2 composite keys

Comment: I wanted to point out (because I missed it) that it is the _relative order_ and not _position_ of the columns which must match, and also that it is the order of the _columns in the table_ that matters rather than the _order of selectors_ in the foreign key. For instance, if you explicitly assign a column order, as required for composite keys, you need to use the same column order in both primary and dependent tables. There is an affordance for finding out-of-order columns with the same name between both tables but that can miss the case where primary.Id is supposed to match dependent.PrimaryId

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you've set the relationship with the columns flipped. Note that the first error states that the type of `operation_date_data` does not match `operation_id`. It should matching with the data not id in the related object. Check the referential constraint on your association to make sure the columns are in the same order.

Comment: I've just checked the relationship in SSMS, just to be sure - the columns are not flipped.

Comment: No, you need to check it in the EDMX.

Comment: The point is the edmx file does not generate properly. I've checked some of my other databases, to be sure there is nothing wrong with VS - everything works great. For the problematic database with operations and operation_category_element_relations tables the edmx file content is somewhat strange. I've edited my questions and put the content of edmx file there.

Comment: To fix it, you will need to modify the EDMX. You can do this through the designer by clicking on the association and selecting the elipses button next to the referential constraints. Alternatively, you can edit the EDMX directly (in the Association node for the CSDL) which should be retained if you need to regenerate in the future.